# How to fetch data dynamically in Java Swing from MS Access database?

Tags: java, swing

I am working in Java swing and trying to fetch data from MS Access database dynamically. Problem is it is only fetching first row but database contain four rows. I know the reason why it is fetching only first row again and again but after applying various logic I can't find a way to fetch second or further records. Please help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Ex_test extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Ex_test ob=new Ex_test();
    }
    public Ex_test()
    {
    super("Array");
    int[] id=new int[15];
    String[] name=new String[15];
    int[] contact=new int[15];

    try
    {
        Connection con;
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test");
        st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("select * from test");
        while (rs.next())
        {
            for (int i=0;i<=3 ;i++ )
            {
                id[i]=rs.getInt("id");
                name[i]=rs.getString("sname");
                contact[i]=rs.getInt("contact");
                System.out.println(""+id[i]+name[i]+contact[i]);                
            }               
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }   
    setSize(1000,1000);
    setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You still haven't accepted any answer from any of your previous questions. Why should we continue helping?

Comment: I think now I have accepted. And Please don't stop helping. stackoverflow is the best.

Comment: @camickr I hope, the way to accept an answer is to click the up arrow in the left hand side where tool tip says This answer is useful.

Comment: @user3701323 If it is your question, you simply click on the checkmark beneath the up and down arrows. Take a [quick tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of how StackOverflow works.

Comment: @CanadianDavid Thanks a lot. I got it. Now I will accept useful answer from previous questions. And please don't stop helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rs.next()` moves the cursor to the next item in the `ResultSet` or in other words, gets the next row in your `ResultSet`. Therefore, you should remove the `for` loop to get the next rows:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    id[i]=rs.getInt("id");
    name[i]=rs.getString("sname");
    contact[i]=rs.getInt("contact");
    System.out.println(""+id[i]+name[i]+contact[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 But you might want to use terminology that the OP might understand, rather than saying *"moves the cursor to the next item"*, which technically correct, you could use *"moves (or gets) the next row"* or some such...or both so the user becomes familiar with the terminology ;)